# Count points within a spesific interval

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, iteration

I have a classes that represents pseudorandom generator. And I want to count

amount of numbers in each interval. Class Interval has public member function `bool isIninterval(float num)`:

```
bool Interval::isIninterval(float num)
{
    return ((unsigned)(num - a) <= (b - a));
}
```

Here is Random generator:

```
class R_G_9
{
public:
    R_G_9() {};
    float getNextRand();
    void printFrequency();
    void countFrequency();
private:
    R_G_1 r1;
    map<Interval, int> intervals;
};
```

I have a map where key is a class Interval and value is number of floats that are within this interval. I have a loop iterating a map. I want a loop to stop when it fins an interval that holds float, that was randomly generated. 
Here is function that counts frequency where I have problem:

```
void R_G_9::countFrequency()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        intervals.insert(make_pair(Interval(i, i + 10), 0));
    }
    const long maxRands = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxRands; ++i)
    {
        float r = getNextRand();
        typedef map<Interval, int>::const_iterator Iter ;
        Iter p = intervals.begin();
        for (; p != intervals.end(); ++p)
            if (p->first->isIninterval(r)) break;  // is not OK
        // do something
    }
}
```

I don`t know what to do to make it possible to check if a float in interval. I tried.

```
if (p->first->isIninterval(r)) break;
```

and

```
if (p->first.isIninterval(r)) break;
```

But it says that i can not do this (score under it with red wavy line). Maybe someone knows how to do it correct, I would appreciate it.

Comment: How is that related to pointers? Points are not pointers...!?

Comment: Please attach compiler error message - it will be very helpful

Comment: before compilation it score under it with red wavy line.

Comment: @stacy_stacy, then please attach the message VS shows in a hint toolbar when you hover a mouse over this red-underscored text. For both options

Comment: @alexeykusmin It says about incompatible types.

Comment: @stacy_stacy, please attach the exact text

Comment: @alexeykusmin Iter p ошибка: объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с функцией-членом, тип объекта const Interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93251/discussion-between-alexeykuzmin0-and-stacy-stacy).

Comment: In two seconds I will translate it into Inglish

Comment: @stacy_stacy, russian is my native, but yes, it will be helpful for other readers

Comment: Map's value type is std::pair<const Key, T>, i.e. Key is const, but you are calling non-const function on it first->isIninterval. Also the function "isIninterval" is very suspicious, I doubt that it works. You are really casting float to unsigned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to mark `isInInterval` as `const`:

```
bool Interval::isIninterval(float num) const
{
    return ((unsigned)(num - a) <= (b - a));
}
```

After this fix the following code should work:

```
if (p->first.isIninterval(r)) break;
```

The compiler message you attached states that the `Interval` you use (`p->first`) is a const variable (you cannot change key of a value in a map). Adding const to the end of method declaration you can allow this method execution for const values.